# DialogFragment / orientation switch

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a fairly simple DialogFragment. It looks something like:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private String mData = "empty";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
        // setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mydialog, container);

        ....

        return view;
    }

    public setData(String _data) {
        mData = _data;
    }
}
```

I load this fragment like so from my `FragmentActivity`:

```
FragmentManager lFM = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment lDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
lDialog.setData("not empty");
lDialog.show(lFM, "MyDialog");
```

The code as above works fine. However I would like to retain the fragment on an orientation switch so that the mData field is preserved. If I add `setRetainInstance(true);` (and after sticking in some debug) I can see that the fragment is indeed retained on an orientation switch - `onCreate()` is not being called this time. I can see `onCreateView()` is being called and I return a correct `View` object, but the dialog is not shown on the screen. What am I missing?

Comment: what is your fragmentactivity android:configChanges in manifest?

Comment: It isn't set - my application doesn't handle any config changes itself. I prefer my activity to be restarted on an orientation change anyway - the problem is that my fragment is (correctly) retained but not shown.

Comment: Avoid using `android:configChanges` as possible, Google doesn't recommend it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following logic in your fragment activity:

Use the put methods to store values in onSaveInstanceState():

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
  icicle.putBoolean("dialogDisplayed", value);    // set value = true when displayin dialog...
}
```

And restore the values in onCreate():

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   if (icicle != null){
     value = icicle.getBoolean("dialogDisplayed");
   }
   if(value)
       //Display Dialog here.... 

 }
```

Comment: Don't forget "null check" in `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: Implemented slightly different but I'll accept the answer - thanks

Comment: This do nothing when you know dialog has shown. You need dialog instance to dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answer that baboo gave me I implemented the solution as follows .. I hope this is correct (at least it works ok ...)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // ....

  FragmentManager lFM = getSupportFragmentManager();
  if(lFM.findFragmentByTag("MyDialog")!=null)
    ((MyDialogFragment)lFM.findFragmentByTag("MyDialog")).show(lFM, "MyDialog");

  // ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The dialog fragment should be preserved automatically as long as you do the following:

1. If you call an Activity onSaveInstanceState(), **make sure you call the super function!!!!**. In my case, that was the key. Also make sure you do the same thing in the Fragment.
2. If you use `setRetainInstance`, you will need to manually store off the values and re-apply them. Otherwise, you should be able to not worry about it, in most cases. If you're doing something a bit more complicated, you might need to `setRetainInstance(true)`, but otherwise ignore it. In my case, I needed to use it to store a random seed for one of my classes, but otherwise I was okay.
3. Some people have complained about a bug in the support library, where a dismiss message is sent when it shouldn't be. The latest support library seems to have fixed that, so you shouldn't need to worry about that.

You shouldn't need to do anything fancy like manually store off the fragment, it should be done automatically if you follow these steps.